# turn on echo temporarily

Tags: windows, cmd, dos, echo

I am creating a batch file and have turned echo off with @ECHO OFF however I need to demonstrate one of the commands in the batch onscreen how would I temporarily turn on ECHO

Answer (score 3):

Syntax:

```
ECHO [ON | OFF]
ECHO [Message]
```

A simple `ECHO ON` should solve this mystery.