# Turn on echo for a single command in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

In a Windows Batch file, if I had echoing enabled (the default), I could disable echoing an individual command by prefixing an `@`, eg:

```
some_command_that_will_be_echoed
@some_command_that_wont_be_echoed
```

However, I have echoing disabled with `@echo off`, but from time to time I *would* like to echo the command.  Is there some magic equivalent?  eg:

```
@echo off
some_command_that_wont_be_echoed
<unknown_magic_prefix> some_command_that_will_be_echoed
```

I found this question: [turn on echo temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036250/turn-on-echo-temporarily), but that essentially says 'turn echo on, do your thing, then turn it off again'.  I *could* do that, but I'm hoping for something more elegant.

EDIT: this [Windows batch file: how to enable inline echo of a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125346/windows-batch-file-how-to-enable-inline-echo-of-a-command) turned up in the releated questions list; it is basically the same question as mine, and about as successful!

EDIT2: in the interests of providing context, below is a section of what I'm up to.  Note that I've adorned it with C-style comments for the benefit of this post; they're not in the real script.

```
@echo off   // Because I don't want the bulk of the commands displayed. 
            // (In fact it's worse than that, this file is called from another
            //  with echo already disabled.)

title CMD Window with SVN enabled

set PATH=  ...  // my new path which happens to include SVN this time

svn --version --quiet   // This command outputs just the SVN version as a number
                        // but it gets rather lost on its own, and the 'full'
                        // output is too wordy.  My belief is that if the entire
                        // command was echoed, it would provide a perfect 
                        // context.

echo SVN version is:    // This is an obvious alternative, simply putting a
svn --version --quiet   // message before the actual command.

echo svn --version --quiet  // Or even just echoing the command 'by hand'
svn --version --quiet

+@svn --version --quiet   // This imaginary syntax would be the gold-standard

always_echo( svn --version --quiet )   // This function would be acceptable, but
                                       // its definition eludes me and seems 
                                       // clunky

<some batch file magic preamble>    // This would be okay, but would get arduous
svn --version --quiet               // if it was long-winded or had to be done a
<some batch file magic to close>    // few times or more.
```

But just to emphasise, while this is a specific example which would be relatively easy to 'fix', I'm after a more generic solution that I could use in other situations that might not be so simple.

@Compo reasonably pointed out that `@echo off` is not very elegant in itself.  That's fair, but a) it's already enabled in this case and b) it's pretty idiomatic.  I like the clarity of this (imaginary syntax):

```
@echo off
command_1    // not echoed
command_2    // not echoed
+@command_3  // IS echoed and stands out
command_4    // not echoed
```

versus

```
@command_1    // not echoed
@command_2    // not echoed
command_3     // IS echoed and gets a little lost
@command_4    // not echoed
```

Clearly that's a subjective opinion, but boils down to a desire to decorate only the uncommon case.

And finally, if it's *really* not possible, then fair enough, but there's no harm in being *sure* :)

Comment: We are talking about batch files there is nothing more elegant.  The link you have there is the solution.

Comment: Okay, how about 'more elegant' in the sense of `some_wrapper_function( command_I_want_echoed )`, which will restore the state to whatever it was, be it off or on?

Comment: Do not use `@echo off` to globally turn `echo`ing off, it is in itself inelegant. Use the `@` prefix, and just remove it where necessary, that is the elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Compo, that is a very fair point.  Notwithstanding, I find that clutters things; is it not cleaner to highlight the special cases and have the common case un-decorated?

Comment: How about you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58732724/edit) to include some real code, and then show us which line or lines require `echo`ing and which do not. That would at least give us the opportunity to offer solutions you may deem more elegant.

Comment: @Compo, I'm not trying to be awkward with my assessment of elegance!  With regards to a real example, I'm not convinced it would add anything much.  In fact, I specifically didn't include my real code because I didn't want it to detract from the trust of the question.  Notwithstanding, I'll add something representative now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a small macro (`%+@%`), it will show the command and then executes it.

```
@echo off    
call :define_macro

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=content

%+@% ver
%+@% ver /?
%+@% echo %var% !var!
exit /b

:define_macro
(set \n=^^^

)
set ^"+@=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion %\n%
    for /F "tokens=1,*" %%1 in ("!time: =0! !argv!") do (%\n%
        endlocal%\n%
        echo %%1 Execute: %%2%\n%
        endlocal%\n%
        %%2%\n%
      )%\n%
    ) ELSE setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv="

exit /b
```

Outputs:

> 14:04:08,05 Execute: ver
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1069]
>   14:04:08,05 Execute: ver /?
>   Displays the Windows version.
>
> VER
>   14:04:08,05 Execute: echo content !var!
>   content content

Edited: From the suggestions of sst, I removed the helper function, but to be able to use a custom and nice prefix, I decided against the `echo on` inside the macro.

Comment: Nice macro. The call to `:__execHelper` can be eliminated by replacing it with `echo on %\n%` - `for %%# in (%%#) do %%1 %\n%` - `echo off %\n%`. And replacing `for %%# in (1 2) do ...` with `for %%# in (%%# 2) do ...`. After these modifications there would be no need for  `echo I will execute: !argv!%\n%`

Comment: @sst Thanks, it was really simple to avoid the helper function. But your `FOR` loop has to be changed to `FOR /F "tokens=*" ...` to avoid problems with commands including `?` or `*`. But even if it's possible to use the `echo on` inside the macro, I don't like the messy output (with the current prompt and new lines).

Comment: As I feared, the syntax is a little hairy, but the spirit of the solution is spot on, thanks.  It's a nice touch to just echo the command before executing, rather than messing around with changing the echo mode itself.

Comment: @EddInglis Batch macros are almost *hairy*, but you can even move them into an own *library-batch* file, you don't need to see or understand them

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which may help you:

```bat
@(
    Echo On
    Title CMD Window with SVN enabled
    Set "PATH=%PATH%;D:\ummy\directory"
)
svn --version --quiet
@(
    Rem All other none echoed commands here
    Pause
    Echo Off
    Exit /B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:echo
    @echo on
    %*
    @set __echo_errorlevel=%ERRORLEVEL%
    @echo off
exit /b %__echo_errorlevel%
```

Use this like `call :echo command arg1 arg2 arg3...`. (If you call `:echo` while `@echo` is `on`, this will turn it `off`.)